# Have I been hacked - getting new site setup email for 8 localhost wordpress sites

Tags: hacked

I've just found some emails in my spam folder saying a new wordpress site has been set up on my local server, for 8 already existing wordpress installs.

[image]

I'm assuming its been hacked but am not 100%. My computer was being weird when I think it happened, not allowing me to get online...

Comment: How would your localhost get hacked? Literally nobody else could access that site.

Comment: Thanks for response. I was thinking If I logged into a WordPress site online that had been hacked, then they could run a hack through my browser somehow. Its just weird those Wordpress sites should all email a clean install notice at the same time, especially since the network was behaving suspiciously at the time.

Comment: You're right. It was just coincidence I think... see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it was just the original install emails coming through all at the same time from localhost, very late, some 2 years ago.

I can't find the original emails but then if they went into spam like these emails I wouldn't find them.

So I don't know, hopefully its just a late localhost bottleneck finally unbottlenecking.